Colorless Higgs
In the Standard model, the Higgs boson has both hypercharge and weak hypercharge, but it is colourless.
This property make sure that in the covariant derivative of the Higgs field no gluon coupling appears and $SU(3)$ is left untouched.
Being impossible to detect (at current accelerator luminosity) isolated gluons, and hence its mass, how do we know that this is actually the case?
I am confident that even if the Higgs is coloured the breaking of $SU(2)$ should not affect this, but how do we know that Higgs-style breaking of $SU(3)$ doesn't happen?
Is a coloured Higgs ruled out by some experimental data?

All the scattering amplitudes would change because there's now a Higgs-gluon vertex, no?

I think thats true but im not sure how much would they change, if at all. This should be noticeable enough in the end even if the scattering amplitudes change by very little much

We know that $SU(3)$ is exact because as far as we can tell gluons don't have bare masses. Also if you think about it, shouldn't we be seeing the decay of Higgs bosons into $q$ + $l$ systems? We only see decays into colourless products. Indeed if the Higgs were colored we'd expect to see a lot of such decay channels in scattering expirements.

@Mike that could be an answer to me :)

Glad that I was helpful.

Have you specified the SU(3) representation your mock-Higgs is meant to be in, and how its v.e.v. comports with that group? It seems you are proposing some type of strong-EW mixing...

When you have an unbroken gauge symmetry, there are massless gauge bosons. The number of massless gauge bosons is the dimensionality of the adjoint representation of the symmetry group. So for SU(3), there are 8 gauge bosons, called "gluons." For unbroken SU(2), there would be 3 gauge bosons. And if it remained unbroken, those gauge bosons would have all the same properties (they wouldn't have different electric charges, and they wouldn't have different masses - or masses at all). Because SU(2) is broken, we have three distinct particles, the $W^+$, $W^-$, and $Z^0$. They have different charges and masses.
The fact that SU(3) is unbroken is proven insofar as we know the 8 gluons are massless and have the same properties. Here's a paper finding an experimental limit on the gluon mass Upper Limits on a Possible Gluon Mass. But actually I don't think this is really the best way to check if SU(3) is broken. Rather, consider the neutral pion (or the + or - charged ones). There are colors of neutral pion: blue-antiblue, red-antired, and green-antigreen. If SU(3) was broken, these three pions would have different masses, and they would probably also have different properties under some as-of-yet undiscovered charge. I can't find any papers at the moment that try to limit these mass differences, but suffice to say nobody has observed any evidence of a pion mass splitting.
